# Simulate vs props - On Change event using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, onchange, enzyme

I am trying to run test for multiple onChange events. The test right now passes with the following code but does not affect its COVERAGE, means incorrect

```
wrapper.find('Datasubjects').props().onChange({City:{target:{value:'test'}}})
```

But it fails if I use the following:

```
wrapper.find('Datasubjects').find('input[id="city-label-id"]').simulate('change',{City:{target: {value:'test'}}} )
```

Here is part of Render(), showing the onChange event that I am trying to test:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.quickFilterModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>

<div className='advanced-search-modal-body'>

<label>City</label>
<input id='city-label-id' onChange={(e) => {this.setState({advancedFilter: {...this.state.advancedFilter, City: e.target.value}})}}  value={this.state.advancedFilter.City}/>
</div>
```

Here is my part of my test file using Jest Enzyme for React JS

```
   beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><Datasubjects {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>)

  it("Test onChange event on City - Label", () => {
baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
wrapper.find('Datasubjects').setState({
    advancedFilter:{
        City:'test-city'
    },
    quickFilterModalOpen:true
    });

wrapper.update() 
wrapper.find('Datasubjects').find('input[id="city-label-id"]').props().onChange({City:{target:{value:'test-city'}}})
})
```

Comment: This is Enzyme, isn't it? The question doesn't even mention it.

Comment: I didnt see `Datasubjects ` in your code.. try without it `wrapper.find('input[id="city-label-id"]').simulate('change',{City:{target: {value:'test'}}} )`

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii it fails. The reason why I added.( 'Datasubjects'), using mount and browserrouter

Comment: @estus correct it is, and it does mention above test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`simulate` and prop call are interchangeable, this is basically what `simulate` does internally. `simulate` is expected to be deprecated in next Enzyme version because it's redundant.

Two provided snippets aren't interchangeable because they are applied to different components. In case `onChange` prop is called, it should be called on the same component:

```
wrapper
.find('Datasubjects')
.find('input[id="city-label-id"]')
.props()
.onChange({City:{target:{value:'test'}}})
```

Comment: Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: Then proper selectors is the concern here, not `simulate` vs `props()`. This is a different question and I cannot answer it precisely because the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  I see several problems here. Real router shouldn't be used in unit tests. Use MemoryRouter. I wouldn't expect `.find('Datasubjects')` to work at all, it should be `.find(Datasubjects)`. Add `.to.have.lengthOf(1)` assertion everywhere you're not sure that a selector is 100% workable, see https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html for example.

Comment: Thanks. But i had seen posts and answers that do uses BrowserRouter when they are mounting the component.  Some of my other files worked just fine. I will look into it. I wrote the following  console.log(wrapper.state()) and setState and as result = null or reactWrapper:{}.

Comment: I did the following : console.log('input[id="city-label-id"]', wrapper.find(Datasubjects).length); Received length =1.

Comment: so I ran the code    expect(wrapper.find(Datasubjects).find('input[id="city-label-id"]').length).toBe(1); without quotations. Received = 0

Comment: As I said, the question doesn't contain all necessary code. I can't say why it doesn't work without MCVE. I'd suggest to seek the problem in <Modal>. There's no evidence that <input> remains a child of Datasubjects once it's rendered. That's the problem with doing integration tests like you do. Once there are many units, you don't know which one fails you. I'd suggest to mock everything but tested unit in this test, including Modal.

Comment: I will add the code into a codesandbox later today or tomorrow. If i figure out , ill post here as answer and try to explain where the mistake was