# What is the difference between simulating the actions & calling them manually in jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

What is the difference between simulating the actions & calling them manually?

I have mounted the component using enzyme.

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CreateNavItemForm />
  </Provider>,
)

const formWrapper = wrapper.find('CreateNavItemForm').first()
```

What is the difference and which approach is better?

```
   const title = 'title'
```

1st:

```
formWrapper
   .find('input')
   .at(0)
   .props()
   .onChange(title)
```

2nd:

```
formWrapper
  .find('input')
  .at(0)
  .simulate('change', { target: { value: title } })
```

Comment: It might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405175/simulate-vs-props-on-change-event-using-jest-and-enzyme. You can find more information about that on GitHub: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2173

Answer (score 1):

A good question, there is a difference, when you checking using simulate, you are mimic more real scenario.

Furthermore, you are checking that your component is wired properly: for example, consider that this is your component:

```
const SpecialInput = ({onChange}) => (<input name />);
```

This component is not using the `onChange` at all, your test with prop usage will pass, but in real scenario it won't work as expected.

For addition, when you are testing using prop usage, that means that you are aware of the inner implementation of the component, so, if in the future you will change the implementation but not the functionality you will need to **change the test**, which is a smell of bad test.